# Inkscape stopped functioning suddenly

Tags: freeze, inkscape

I have been working in Inkscape for the past week. Last night, Inkscape suddenly stopped functioning. That is:

- It takes a very long time to load. When started, it looks frozen, Ubuntu asks me if I want to force it to quit, but if I wait 1-2 minutes, it recovers
- If I try to perform any operation to edit an image in Inkscape, at each click/action, it freezes for a few minutes.

What I tried:

- uninstall and then install again Inkscape - did not help

My system:
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

[image]

Comment: Please launch it via terminal (the command is ```inkscape```) and post the output to your question.And have you tried the apt version or the [AppImage](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/gnulinux/appimage/dl/) ?

Comment: Long pauses may indicate high memory usage or swapping. Use the `top` and `free` terminal applications (or Desktop Monitor) to observe CPU and memory use during one of these long pauses.